# How can I execute a JQUERY / JS, a notification on the screen?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My question is this. I have a website that I am developing and I am facing the following problem that I can not solve. I make queries against mysql with php and I keep it in cookies errors or well-made queries, and I want the user on the screen to get notified that it has been completed correctly. For the notifications I am using the following js / Jquery, it is designed to run when I receive a click of a button id, but I want to execute it when this query is finished. Can you help me?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

"use strict";

var i = -1;
var toastCount = 0;
var $toastlast;

var getMessage = function () {
    var msgs = ['Ejemplo de notificación'];
    i++;
    if (i === msgs.length) {
        i = 0;
    }

    return msgs[i];
};


$('#newLista_alert').click(function () {
    var shortCutFunction = 'success';
    var msg = 'Preparada para meterle canciones';
    var title = 'Lista creada existosamente' || '';
    var $showDuration = $(300);
    var $hideDuration = $(1000);
    var $timeOut = $(2000);
    var $extendedTimeOut = $(500);

    var toastIndex = toastCount++;

    var addClear = $('#addClear').prop('checked');

    toastr.options = {
        closeButton: true,
        debug: false,
        newestOnTop: false,
        progressBar: true,
        positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right' || 'toast-top-right',
        preventDuplicates: false,
        onclick: null
    };

    toastr.options.showEasing = 'swing';

    toastr.options.hideEasing = 'linear';

    toastr.options.showMethod = 'fadeIn';

    toastr.options.hideMethod = 'fadeOut';



    var $toast = toastr[shortCutFunction](msg, title); // Wire up an event handler to a button in the toast, if it exists
    $toastlast = $toast;

    if (typeof $toast === 'undefined') {
        return;
    }

    if ($toast.find('#okBtn').length) {
        $toast.delegate('#okBtn', 'click', function () {
            alert('you clicked me. i was toast #' + toastIndex + '. goodbye!');
            $toast.remove();
        });
    }
    if ($toast.find('#surpriseBtn').length) {
        $toast.delegate('#surpriseBtn', 'click', function () {
            alert('Surprise! you clicked me. i was toast #' + toastIndex + '. You could perform an action here.');
        });
    }
    if ($toast.find('.clear').length) {
        $toast.delegate('.clear', 'click', function () {
            toastr.clear($toast, { force: true });
        });
    }
});

function getLastToast() {
    return $toastlast;
}
$('#clearlasttoast').click(function () {
    toastr.clear(getLastToast());
});
$('#cleartoasts').click(function () {
    toastr.clear();
});
});
```

MY CODE FOR MYSQL

```
 <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_REQUEST['newLista'])){

$nombrelista = $_REQUEST['nombrelista'];
$usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];

require_once "../biblioteca.php";

$db = ConectaDb($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);    

$consulta="INSERT INTO lista_musica (nombre,usuario) VALUES (:lista,:usuario)";

$result=$db->prepare($consulta);

    if ($result->execute([":lista" => $nombrelista, ":usuario" => $usuario,])){
        setcookie('result_musica','0',time()+10);
        header ('location: ../../ui-musica.php');
    }
    else{
        echo "LISTA NO SE PUDO CREAR";
    }   
}

?>
```

Comment: Look up the jQuery.ajax() function and use it at the point where you want to call the PHP, most likely in one of your click functions.

Comment: See also many other questions on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=insert+database+record+php+jquery

Comment: I need that when I enter the if it has been inserted correctly, skip this js when entering the page of ui-music.php again. You understand me?

Comment: With AJAX you do not need the user to leave the page, so you can remove the `header(..` and `setcookie(..` lines from your php and just `echo "SUCCESS";`. You can then access that using jQuery.ajax(). If you want to remember this over multiple sessions you can set the cookie in jQuery using $.cookie()

Comment: Okay, Thanks, i try this

Comment: Apologies: $.cookie() is actually a jQuery plugin, so you can use the core `document.cookie()`  javascript functionality instead if you don't want to use the plugin: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp